# Manifest merger error with com.google.android.material:material

Tags: android, android-studio, android-support-library

I am getting following error :

> Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
>   Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
>   Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
>   Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
>   Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
>   Duplicate class android.support.v4.os.IResultReceiver$Stub$Proxy found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.0) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:26.1.0)
>   .......

andin my gradle file there is following dependencies

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
 }
```

I do not know what is the problem I tried multiple solution including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50676100/program-type-already-present-android-support-v4-os-resultreceivermyresultrecei/51263999) but did not get rid of this. Please help

Comment: hope this link helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756647/duplicate-classes-from-androidx-and-com-android-support

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a conflict between androidX and support libs.

If you are not supporting yet androidX you need to replace

`implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'` by `implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'`.

If you still want to use the material version, make sure your `gradle.properties` file has androidX and Jetifier enabled.

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Make sure you follow the necessary setup to use material. Check it out [here](https://material.io/develop/android/docs/getting-started/).