# APK creation failure due to Duplicate class android.support

Tags: android, android-studio, libraries, androidx

After upgrading Android Studio (forced via prompt) the following error occurs when attempting to create an APK file: 
`Duplicate class android.support.customtabs.ICustomTabsCallback found     in modules browser-1.0.0-runtime.jar (androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0)    and jetified-anroid-support-customtabs-23.3.0.jar (anroid-support-    customtabs-23.3.0.jar)`
There are many of them...

I applied the fix recommended in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756647/duplicate-classes-from-androidx-and-com-android-support): which is to add

```
android.useAndroidX=true and android.enableJetifier=true
```

to the gradle.properties file

This did not work for me.

What can I look for to fix?

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56029393/why-im-getting-duplicate-class-when-running-my-android-project/56029604#56029604

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you knew this or not but Google has now stopped future support for the Support libraries like the one you have used `jetified-anroid-support-customtabs-23.3.0.jar`
Fear not, because instead the support has been moved towards AndroidX, as stated `androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0`.

So, with a glance, I see that you have two duplicate classes that arise from both AndroidX library as well as the Support Library.

To Fix:
Check your dependencies, and make sure there is no support library version, and instead migrate everything to AndroidX. This can be done both manually as well as via Refactor>Migrate to AndroidX... Do note that some libraries need to be updated manually. 
More about AndroidX you can see here:
[What is AndroidX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51280090/what-is-androidx)

Hope this helps.