# How to resolve conflict between Android support library and AndroidX?

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

I'm a unity developer that for solving conflict try to export my project to android studio.

I use both firebase and vungle library. firebase depends on androix-core and vungle depends on support-compat. if i compile both of them i receive compile error:

```
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (:androidx.core.core-1.0.0:) and support-compat-27.1.1.jar (support-compat-27.1.1.jar)
```

if i comment one of them i receive runtime error when game starts. what can i really do?

thanks

Comment: the answer is already given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756647/duplicate-classes-from-androidx-and-com-android-support)

Comment: @kfir88 adding use androidx  in gradle.properies not working still bowth libraries in build.gradle and conflicts

Comment: Did you try all they said in the right answer?

Comment: @kfir88 yes i did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756647/duplicate-classes-from-androidx-and-com-android-support) points out that the best approach is to stick to AndroidX as is the new library to replace the Android Support, however using androidx in gradle.properties only means that your project is going to use AndroidX but if your classes over the project are still importing the Android Support libraries the same error is going to popup.

If you go to the vungle support site [here](https://support.vungle.com/hc/en-us/articles/360002922871-Get-Started-with-Vungle-Android-or-Amazon-SDK-v-6), there is a section that talks about AndroidX compatibility and says:

> AndroidX Compatibility
>   Vungle Android SDK 6.4.11 or earlier versions do not officially support AndroidX. Publishers must use migration tool that is available from Android Studio to transform the SDK and its dependencies (third-party libraries) for AndroidX compatibility. The official support for AndroidX will be available with 6.5.0 which is currently in early access stage, and that version would not need any further transformation to be AndroidX compatible. Please reach out through your Account Manager for early access to 6.5.0 if you needed.

So, you need to import your vungle library to Android Studio and follow the guides ([this one](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate)), to migrate the entire project to AndroidX and then compile the library and use it over your Unity project. However, I must warn you that this is tricky, sometimes the migrating tool of Android Studio doesn't change all the use cases of the Android Support and even sometimes it doesn't update them to the current AndroidX classes, and you might have to go through each file of the library changing every android support reference to AndroidX, and that might take you days, depending on how big the library is.

OR, and this is a big or, you have to wait for the Vungle Android SDK 6.5.0 that will be compatible with AndroidX.

PD: As stated by Vungle support site, you can also get the current early access SDK of the Vungle 6.5.0, but that might contain bugs as it is still at development.

Comment: so all it means to have both vungle and firebase in our project we have to wait?

Comment: Kind of, you have to wait for the 6.5.0 release, update your vungle to that version and then it will work, otherwise you can migrate yourself the vungle library to AndroidX

Answer (score 1):

Add these to your gradle properties and from clicking on file in android studio invalidate Cache restart your studio

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Vungle SDK supports androidx since 6.5, and it is in early access right now.If you want to use 6.4.11, it will be great to use Android Studio Gradle tools to do the migration as other answers mentioned. Then the issue should be fixed with SDK 6.4.11.
But **in case, someone does not want to export an Android Studio project and still want to use SDK 6.4.11.** You can follow the document [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/jetifier) to migrate Vungle SDK by yourself without Android Studio.
What you need to do is:

1. Download jetifier and unzip it
2. Use terminal and cd to the folder(mac)
3. Download the [SDK 6.4.11](https://publisher.vungle.com/sdk/sdks/android) and Drag the SDK 6.4.11 jar/aar to the folder jetifier-standalone⁩/bin

The last steps run the command below:

```
./jetifier-standalone -i publisher-sdk-android-6.4.11.aar -o publisher-sdk-android-6.4.11-androidx.aar
```

OR

```
./jetifier-standalone -i vungle-android-sdk-6.4.11.jar -o vungle-android-sdk-6.4.11-androidx.jar
./jetifier-standalone -i vng-moat-mobile-app-kit-2.5.1.jar -o vng-moat-mobile-app-kit-2.5.1-androidx.jar
```

Please make sure to convert two libs if you use the jar file to integrate.

Please use [JD-GUI](http://java-decompiler.github.io/) to check the jar/aar and make sure the migration has been done. I met a failure migration without any error once. So it will be great to check it.
You can check the file below:
[image]
[image]

**At last, if you DO NOT want to do it by yourself, please feel free to download the migrated [aar](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i4d9n2js1pcti3b/publisher-sdk-android-6.4.11-androidx.aar?dl=0) file from my dropbox.** I am sure it will be available for a while.
Please let me know if anyone need jars.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX...
```

and rebuild the project after that

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Refactor -> Migrate to AndroidX
and rebuild the project after that
```

OR Replace in gradle-Module-app

```
 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.+'
 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
```

with

```
'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
```