# how to resolve A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

Tags: java, android, build

Having this Error while trying to debug the application

also updated these two properties in Gradle.properties

```
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
```

using

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
       
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 192
        versionName "2.2.57"
}
```

> Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
>
> > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> > Duplicate class androidx.collection.LruCache found in modules collection-1.1.0 (androidx.collection:collection:1.1.0) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.accessibilityservice.AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat
> > found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NavUtils found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat$Builder found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ServiceCompat found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ShareCompat found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ShareCompat$IntentBuilder found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.app.ShareCompat$IntentReader found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.app.TaskStackBuilder found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.content.IntentCompat found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.content.pm.ActivityInfoCompat found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.database.DatabaseUtilsCompat found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.os.ParcelableCompat found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.os.ParcelableCompatCreatorCallbacks found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.util.DebugUtils found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.util.LogWriter found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.util.TimeUtils found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.view.AccessibilityDelegateCompat found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.view.MenuCompat found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.view.MenuItemCompat found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.view.MotionEventCompat found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.view.VelocityTrackerCompat found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.view.ViewCompat found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.view.ViewConfigurationCompat found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.view.ViewGroupCompat found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityEventCompat found in
> > modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat found in
> > modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityManagerCompat$AccessibilityStateChangeListenerCompat
> > found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat found in
> > modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.view.accessibility.AccessibilityRecordCompat found in
> > modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.core.widget.EdgeEffectCompat found in modules core-1.3.2-runtime (androidx.core:core:1.3.2) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorAdapter found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime
> > (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorAdapter$ChangeObserver found in
> > modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime
> > (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorAdapter$MyDataSetObserver found in
> > modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime
> > (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorFilter found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime
> > (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.CursorFilter$CursorFilterClient found in
> > modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime
> > (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.ResourceCursorAdapter found in modules
> > cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime
> > (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime
> > (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter$CursorToStringConverter
> > found in modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime
> > (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.cursoradapter.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter$ViewBinder found in
> > modules cursoradapter-1.0.0-runtime
> > (androidx.cursoradapter:cursoradapter:1.0.0) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.BackStackState found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.BackStackState$1 found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.Fragment found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$InstantiationException found in modules
> > fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$SavedState found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5)
> > and jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$SavedState$1 found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5)
> > and jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$BackStackEntry found in modules
> > fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$OnBackStackChangedListener found
> > in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5)
> > and jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5)
> > and jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5)
> > and jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerState$1 found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime
> > (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5)
> > and jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentState$1 found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime
> > (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5)
> > and jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment$1 found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment$2 found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.fragment.app.SuperNotCalledException found in modules fragment-1.2.5-runtime
> > (androidx.fragment:fragment:1.2.5) and
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManager$LoaderCallbacks found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.app.LoaderManagerImpl$LoaderInfo found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.CursorLoader found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader$ForceLoadContentObserver found in
> > modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.Loader$OnLoadCompleteListener found in modules
> > jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$1 found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$2 found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$3 found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$4 found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$AsyncTaskResult found in
> > modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$InternalHandler found in
> > modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$Status found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.loader.content.ModernAsyncTask$WorkerRunnable found in
> > modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > loader-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager found in
> > modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0-runtime
> > (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$1 found
> > in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0-runtime
> > (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$BroadcastRecord
> > found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0-runtime
> > (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager$ReceiverRecord
> > found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > localbroadcastmanager-1.0.0-runtime
> > (androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerTitleStrip found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerTitleStrip$PageListener found in
> > modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$1 found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$2 found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$ItemInfo found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$LayoutParams found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$OnAdapterChangeListener found in
> > modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$OnPageChangeListener found in
> > modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$PagerObserver found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$SavedState found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$SavedState$1 found in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)
> > Duplicate class androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager$SimpleOnPageChangeListener found
> > in modules jetified-ViewPagerIndicator-2.4.1-runtime
> > (com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1) and
> > viewpager-1.0.0-runtime (androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0)

Is version downgrading is the only Sloution?

Thank you.

Comment: try to downgrade java version to 7 if you are using newer version. sometimes it happens because of that (Hence it is not worked for me may be because of some other dependencies conflict )

Answer (score 4):

Usually I encountered this duplicate error(s) whenever I tried to migrate to a newer version especially in your case, migrating to [androidx](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate).

I recommend you to clean and rebuild, and delete those from your `./gradle`  and `/build` folders to avoid those import/dependencies duplicate issues.  I previously referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55756749/3970630) fix as well and everything is running again.

Comment: yes, sometimes this is the standard  steps for resolve gradle dependencies error. clean , build and delete cache. but it is not worked for me as I also mentioned it in my Question. also follows  same steps that you provided in   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55756647/duplicate-classes-from-androidx-and-com-android-support/55756749#55756749

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the issue by addding below line in gradle.properties file.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4608m
```

Comment: Are you *sure* that your problem was with CheckDuplicatesRunnable reporting "Duplicate class"?  That has nothing to do with the amount of memory you provide Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

For me the error was caused by the combination of several factors.
I changed in the app gradle:

```
 compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}
kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = '17'
}
```

and then changed the version of Kotlin in build.gradle to :

```
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.10' apply false
```

finally, don't forget the compose options if you use compose to the corresponding version based on the Kotlin version, for this case:

```
composeOptions {
    kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion '1.4.3'
}
```

And that solve this error for me.

Answer (score 0):

invalidate cache and restart will fix the problem.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ay6Pm.png)